# Why does the black king evade to f8, and not to h7?

Tags: checkmate, problems

I'm trying to practice with the app https://f-droid.org/en/packages/jwtc.android.chess

Why does the black king go to f8, and not Kh7 instead?

```
 [FEN "r2rb3/1p2RBk1/2pP1ppR/p7/P7/7P/1q3PP1/3Q2K1 w - - 0 1"]

 1. Rxg6+ Kf8 (1...Kh7) 2. Rg8#
```

Comment: Welcome to chess SE! As a general advice if you really want to improve your chess: Try to approach chess problems patiently, how you get to the solution *yourself* by far outweighs the merit of just knowing the answer. In this case, I reckon you would have easily found the answer to your question on your own had you spent the same amount of time you took for the snapshots of the app and posting a question, on the position itself and analysed a few more variations. Curiosity is best served with patience and hard work!

Comment: Evaluating all checks would help you answer this question for yourself

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Kh7 would also result in mate due to Qh5. So both moves are equally "good" Kf8 Rg8 maybe was seen as less obvious than Qh5.

Comment: Thanks. Qh5 would also take care of Kh8.

Comment: And for Kh7, if not Qh5, for whatever reason, Bg8 is also check with Kh8 the only escape.  Mate is then either Qh5 again, or Rh7.